# String comparison issue in PHP

Tags: php, string

That's a ridiculous question but I am trying to figure out watch going one already for some time. I have the following PHP code in which actually I do a simple string comparison but it doesn't work:

```
    $db = new PDO('pgsql:dbname=login;user=postgres;password=postgres;host=localhost;port=5432');
if ($db) {

    // hash the password
    $hashed_password = md5($pword);
    //echo($hashed_password);
    //AND password =:password 
    $stmt = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM members WHERE username =:username AND password =:password ");

    $stmt->bindParam('username', $uname,PDO::PARAM_INT); // bind $uname to parameter
    $stmt->bindParam('password', $hashed_password,PDO::PARAM_INT); // bind $uname to parameter
    $stmt->execute();

    $result = $stmt->fetch();
    $rights = $result['userRights'];
//====================================================
//  CHECK TO SEE IF THE $result VARIABLE IS TRUE
//====================================================
    if ($result) {
        //echo($rights);
        $num_rows = sizeof($result);

        if ($num_rows > 0) {
            //echo($rights);
            if($rights=="write"){
                echo $rights;
                //echo("write");
                //header('Location: http://www.google.com/');

            } 
            //if($result['userRights']=="write") {
                //echo("write");

                //session_start();
                //$_SESSION['login'] = "1";

                //header ("Location: indexx.php");  
            //} 
        }
        else {
            $errorMessage = "Error logging on";
        }   
    }
    else {
        $errorMessage = "Error logging on";
    }
}

else {
    $errorMessage = "Error logging on";
}
```

}

Note: What I try to do is to implement a simple login/logout application. I know that some of the techniques I use are not best practices (e.g. MD5 hashing).

Comment: What do you mean doesn't work? Where is $result set?

Comment: Check size of  $result first.

Comment: there's nothing wrong in your code (except for some closing brackets, but I assume you just left them out when copy pasting). As long as you don't do anything else with `$rights` than what you've shown us, there's no reason it shouldn't work.

Comment: Thanks. result is set outside if statement. ($result = $stmt->fetch();)

Comment: Its true that I have forgotten some parenthesis when copying from my code.  But still doesn't work..

Comment: What is it that doesn't work? Is it not comparing the two strings correctly or is it the echo part you are referring to?

Comment: The echo part doesn't work. Its like it doesn't enter inside the if statement.

Comment: Before your code I've added `$result = array (1, 2, 3);` and ran it on http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it works :)

Comment: Yes exactly. That why its strange. Cause either way doesn't work for me while it should work!!

Comment: Post all of your relevant code exactly as you have it. The code you've currently posted [works fine](http://codepad.org/XuVPgnTr) so it's either you alone have a unique distribution of PHP that's different from millions of other people (unlikely), or the code you've posted is not the code you're actually using.

Comment: Ok. I posted all my code.

Comment: @dkar try `var_dump($result['userRights'])` just before your IF, what does it output. If it says anything other than `string 'write' (length=5)`, then Ta-daa

Comment: @MLeFevre  It outputs this:  string 'write     ' (length=10)

Comment: @dkar then it looks like your $result['userRights'] has some whitespace on it. try `$rights = trim($result['userRights']);`. If that works, then you need to find and fix where your setting `userRights` in the first place and fix it so it doesn't contain any unecessary space.

Comment: Thanks @MLeFevre. As soon as I saw the output I realized it too. Thanks for the help. It seems when I passed the variables into the db I also put some whitespace. Thats really stupid of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @MLeFevre mentioned correctly my code was correct but my initial value which I was checking inside the "if" statement included some white space which cause the whole problem.
I used this functin to trim the content:

```
           trim($result['userRights']);
```

I just post this here in case someone  face similar problem. It didn't even cross my mind that this was causing the issue.